# How to call a function with params and check them

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, contract-debugging, accounts

I want to create a smart contract that users can send a number to and receive an amount of ether.

```
function airdrop(uint val) public payable {
    require(airdrop == true);
    if (val == 0x31){
        msg.sender.transfer(1 ether);    
        airdrop = false;
    }        
}
```

If users send a `1` they get the ether. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check `val` as a `uint`. Your code would look as follows:

```
function airdrop(uint val) public payable {
        require(airdrop == true);
        if (val == 1){
            msg.sender.transfer(1 ether);    
            airdrop = false;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: and how can I send the value? I need it as hex - is it just calling the contract with data = 0x31?

Comment: Send the value in ETH?  You can simply do `msg.sender.transfer(val ether);`

Comment: No, i want to call this from a wallet